# How to take out the specific string

Tags: php

I have a API which generate 3 dynamic value

```
6737766#Success#565151
```

I need middle value, it may be string or integer. How can I bringout that value ?

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way without a regex:

```
$parts = explode("#", '6737766#Success#565151');
echo $parts[1];
```

In PHP 5.4+

```
echo explode("#", '6737766#Success#565151')[1];
```

This just splits the string at the `#` symbol and puts them into an array. We then just need to access the array value we want which is the second array element.

Comment: Adding a quick explanation would be a little bit less spoonfeeder-y

Comment: You're right. It may be obvious to me but not necessarily to everyone.

Comment: I do this all days. Nice answer.